# Java Spring Boot custom validation: generic validation for all enums

Tags: java, enums, annotations

For a SpringBoot project I'm using custom validation using custom annotations.
In particular, I have a lot of enums and I would like to validate if into the inputs there are correct enums values (e.g. from json to DTO objects)

I'm using this approach:
I defined my annotation:

```
@Target( { FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PlatformValidator.class)
public @interface PlatformValidation {

    String message() default "Invalid platform format";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and my validator:

```
public class PlatformValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PlatformValidation, String>
{
    public boolean isValid(String platform, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

        try {
            if (!isNull(platform)) {
                Platform.valueOf(platform);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, can I have a generic enum validation annotation and specify the enum that I need as a parameter of my annotation?

Something like `@MyValidation(enum=MyEnum, message= ...)`

Comment: This should work fine (though you need a different name from `enum` and should probably just use `Class<? extends Enum<?>> value()`). Is there a specific reason you're not simply using the enum as the POJO property type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generics approach is use Java reflection. So the annotation should be:

```
@EnumValidation(enum=YourEnum.class, message=...)
```

The tutorial about reflection: [Jenkov's Tutorial](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/index.html)

Comment: How can I retrieve the parameter 'enum' (that it will be a .class) into my validator (into the isValid method) ?

Comment: @Safari you can retrieve by override method of `initialize` See more at here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#2-creating-the-validator